# iPad embedded YouTube video player stays in fullscreen after stopping it programatically

Tags: ipad, uiwebview, youtube, embed

I have a UIWebView that loads a YouTube video.

The problem is, that if the video is playing in full screen and I reload the web view to "about:blank" to stop the video, the video player remains as the top view in the window's view hierarchy and blocks everything.
Only the black video player remains visible.

Has someone encountered this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: can you please give me code how it's play in full screen. I have problem that video is not going to play in full screen just gives audio output on video...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem.

Using the old embed code ( http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/audio-video/how-to-play-youtube-videos-within-an-application) causes this problem for me. Similarly, the video does not rotate into landscape mode.

I've switched over to the beta code at http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html. Seems to work.

The inability to switch to landscape during playback is still there though.

Comment: can you please paste the code you've used... the link is redirecting to the blank page